# Creating a model that references itself with Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, model

I tried doing the following

```
class SomeModel(db.Model):
    prev = db.ReferenceProperty(SomeModel)
    next = db.ReferenceProperty(SomeModel)
```

but got the following error

> NameError: name 'TrackPointModel' is
>   not defined

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use a [SelfReferenceProperty](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#SelfReferenceProperty)

```
class SomeModel(db.Model):
    prev = db.SelfReferenceProperty()
    next = db.SelfReferenceProperty()
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't having a, say, next property make the prev property superfluous? If I'm not mistaken this works equally well:

```
class SomeModel(db.Model):
    next = db.SelfReferenceProperty(collection_name='prev')
```